# Texture get Invisible

Tags: android, augmented-reality

Hi Guys i m working with Augmented Reality 
having Using Vuforia Qual-Comm 
i m having issue with markers that is when texture get loads on markers then after a short distance texture get invisible. Any one have any idea about this 
need a clue to work with the distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got my answer that is due to the weakness of the markers that get invisible  after short distance due to not recognition marker and  remake them and get them again as marker form VUforia now its working fine